# Strange behavior of Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Below query yielded no results even when there was matching record in the DB.
[image]

- Even the query generated will yield the result when executed in DB.
- Also, query yields the result when "order by" is added to the query.
- No changes in the query parameters.
- Same query works for dev database, yields no result in QA database.
- There is no change in the QA database compared to Dev.

[image]

Comment: Usually is related to a wrong connection string (EF creates DBs and tables so if you use a wrong connection string this is the result but this is not your case) or is related to EF Provider. If you split the line var currentDept ............... before FirstOrDefault you will see the query that EF runs on DB. See what's the differences (in this case is after the EF Provider work so you can eventually see for EF Provider bugs).

Comment: Isn't it just that `ADMINGROUP` is null for the **first** result when not ordering by `DEPARTEMENT`, while it's not null for the **first** result ***after*** the ordering? (You use `FirstOrDefault`)

Comment: you've used firstordefault and your record will be null. but when you used order by the order of records changes and first records must had an value i.e. why you are seeing records in 2nd not in 1st query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add filter for the ADMINGROUP

```
var currentDept = (from d in dbContext.TBLZLISTDEPTs
where d.ADMINGROUP != null
select new 
{
   d.ADMINGROUP
}).FirstOrDefault();
```